# Help requested with integer means

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do there exist two distinct positive integers whose arithmetic mean, geometric mean, and harmonic mean are all integers? In illustrating these three means to students, it would be nice if a non-messy example could be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with any positive integer $r > 1$. This is the GM of $a$ and $b$ if $ab=r^2$. Fix any such $a,b$ with $a \ne b$. Now compute in lowest terms the AM $\frac12(a+b) = \frac{p}{q}$ and the HM $2ab/(a+b) = \frac{r}{s}$. If these are both integers, we are done; if not, just multiply $a$ and $b$ by the LCM of $q$ and $s$.

**Example:** $r=30$

Take $a=12, b=75$, so that $ab=r^2$ (other choices are possible). Then the AM is $87/2$ and the HM is $1200/29$. So we multiply $a$ and $b$ by LCM$(2,29) = 58$ to get $a'=696, b'=4350$. The AM, GM, and HM of $a'$ and $b'$ are $2523, 1740,$ and $1200$.

For a smaller example, you might want to try starting with $r=2$ or $r=3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic mean of a pair of numbers are related by,

$$H=\frac{G^2}{A}.$$